# Use three columns in Order by clause

Tags: sql-server

I am using three columns while sorting the table using an `order by` clause. First column is sorted by ascending order and other two columns are sorted by descending order. In my case all three columns have to sort by ascending order.

Can you please give me solution for this?

Comment: The official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first point of reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can include as many fields as you want in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM the_table ORDER BY a ASC, b ASC, c ASC;
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: So you're saying you get the record (1, 2, 2) before (2, 1, 1)?  That sounds right, since you're sorting by RIU_reportDisplayNumber first.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate.. I recommend leaving this open